# How to create '/proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone' file

Tags: 18.04, kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use Puppeteer. And it [recommends](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#recommended-enable-user-namespace-cloning) me to run 
`sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` to enable the sandbox.

But when I do that on my WSL, it complains `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone: No such file or directory`. And I don't know how to go from there..

Comment: At the time of writing, there is no "Linux kernel" in WSL. So, no init system, no systemd etc. Wait for the next release of WSL2.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the response!